# How do you find expressions without the summation for series?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis

I am taking a calculus course and our professor asked us to show that the following series can be written as

$$\sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^{k+1}  \frac{k}{k^2-\frac{1}{4}} = 1 + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2n+1}$$

To show this using induction is not so hard, but what I am interested in is how one finds the expression. Is there a method in cases like the one above of finding the equivalent equation for series or not?

Comment: In many special cases, the answer is "yes". For instance, when the ratio between consecutive terms is a [rational function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_function) we can often find a closed form in terms of [hypergeometric functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function). There are many references on computing closed forms for series in this way, but two important ones are Knuth, Graham, and Patashnik's _Concrete Mathematics_ and Petkovsek, Wilf, and Zeilberger's _[A=B](https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/AeqB.html)_.

Comment: $$\frac{k}{k^2-\frac{1}{4}}=\frac{4k}{(2k-1)(2k+1)}=\frac{1}{(2k-1)}+\frac{1}{(2k+1)}$$
Then - telescoping.